# Kann ich ein Genitivobjekt so verkürzen?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

Ich habe in der letzten Zeit gelernt, dass es bestimmte Verben gibt, die ein Genitivobjekt fordern.  Wenn ich recht verstehe, im Satz "Ich schäme mich deiner," bezieht sich das Wort "deiner" einfach auf dich, d. h. "deiner" ist nicht possessiv.  Hingegen im Satz "Ich schäme mich deiner Tochter," ist das Wort "deiner" possessiv.

Ist der folgende Satz daher grammatikalisch falsch formuliert?

> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich deiner schämst.

Ich würde denken, dass man da "deiner" verstehen würde, "deiner Tochter" zu meinen.  Da "deiner" aber ein nicht possessives Genitivobjekt für sich ist, bin ich nicht sicher, ob man "deiner Tochter" so verkürzen kann.

Comment: Das ist mal eine tolle Frage und ein schönes Beispiel für echte Mehrdeutigkeit. Kurze Antwort: Grammatikalisch ist nichts auszusetzen, aber es ist mehrdeutig.

Comment: Hinweis von einem native speaker: Auch wenn das in der Theorie so möglich ist, wird man lange nach jemandem suchen müssen der das ernsthaft so ausspricht ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Du verstehst das völlig richtig, und der Satz ist grammatisch korrekt.

> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich deiner schämst.

Beide Interpretationen sind möglich, es kann "deiner" oder "deiner Tochter" gemeint sein. Das heißt, der Satz ist doppeldeutig, die Bedeutung würde man aus dem Kontext schließen müssen. Ohne Kontext weiß ich nicht, welche Bedeutung ich bevorzugen würde.

Eine Möglichkeit, den Bezug eindeutig zu machen, ohne das Wort *Tochter* zu wiederholen, wäre:

> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich *der deinen* schämst.
> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich *deiner selbst* schämst.

In modernem Deutsch wird *schämen* mit Genitiv meist durch *schämen* mit *für* ersetzt, was es auch eindeutig macht, aber auch etwas profaner klingt:

> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich *für deine* schämst.
> Ich schäme mich nicht meiner Tochter, selbst wenn du dich *für dich* schämst.

Comment: "In modernem Deutsch" ... verwendet man aber konsequenterweise auch im ersten Satzteil die Formulierung mit "für".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper mangelnder Konsequenz schäme ich mich da nicht. Man kann das wunderbar mischen.

Comment: Sehr hilfreich, danke.

Comment: +1; man könnte den Satz auch noch mit _... du dich **deiner eigenen** schämst_ umformulieren.